# Xcode - Build fails with Pods cannot find headers

Tags: ios, build, cocoapods, xcode7

Everything was working fine with my project `Xcode 7.3.1` but then I added a new pod and run "pod install" and started to get errors about header files not found.

[image]

This image is an example of the error:

I was reading that sometimes some references to `PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS` disappear so I just want to know how to solve this, where do I have to search for that references to make sure that is missing and how to add that reference.